# Trail slash with multiple htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

I have directory structure like this:

```
public_html
.htaccess[1]
  -apps     
  -.htaccess[2]
    -admin
    -myviwo
```

when I request `http://localhost/mysite/admin` it redirect me to `http://localhost/mysite/apps/admin/` and shows me the content of the admin directory, if I request `http://localhost/mysite/admin/` it doesn't redirect me but it shows me the content of admin directory again which is correct. But I want:

`http://localhost/mysite/admin`

`http://localhost/mysite/admin/`

Both of the above URLs shows me the content of admin directory without redirecting me.

.htaccess [1]

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteBase /
RewriteRule (.*) apps/$1 [L]
```

.htaccess [2]

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^admin/?(.*)$ admin/$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ myviwo/$1 [L]
```

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the admin directory, add an htaccess file with the following:

```
DirectorySlash Off
```

This makes it so mod_dir won't redirect requests for the directory `admin`. However, note that there's an [important reason why directory slash is "on" by default](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_dir.html#directoryslash):

> **Security Warning**
>
> Turning off the trailing slash redirect may result in an information disclosure. Consider a situation where `mod_autoindex` is active `(Options +Indexes)` and `DirectoryIndex` is set to a valid resource (say, index.html) and there's no other special handler defined for that URL. In this case a request with a trailing slash would show the index.html file. **But a request without trailing slash would list the directory contents**.

If that's ok with you, then that's all that you need.

Otherwise, you may need to add a special rule specifically for `admin`. In the `.htaccess[1]` file, add *right below the rewrite base*:

```
RewriteRule ^admin$ apps/admin/ [L]
```

---

EDIT: to make the above rule dynamic, you need to first check if it's a directory:

```
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/apps%{REQUEST_URI} -d
RewriteRule ^(.*[^/])$ apps/$1/ [L]
```

Comment: is there any way to make `RewriteRule ^admin$ apps/admin/ [L]` dynamic? I mean this happen for the all dir inside the apps dir.

Comment: Rule is not executed. seems the conditions never happens